# How to make the whole div clickable?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `div` with contents in it:

```html
<div class="block">
    <img src='...'>
    <span>...</span>
</div>
```

I set up a JavaScript Event Listener when someone clicks on the `div`:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'DIV' && e.target.classList.contains("block")){
        (code)
    }
}
```

It works when I click on the area of ​​the `div` that has no content. But it doesn't works, when I click to the image or to the text.
How can I get this at the whole div working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `event.target` is the element you clicked on. If you do not directly click on the div then your code will not match your tests because you are clicking on a child element.

So when you are using event delegation and you want to know if an element or one of its children is clicked on, you need to walk up the tree to see if it is that element. You can do that with [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.closest('div.block')) {
      console.log('clicked', Date.now());
    }
});
```

```html
<h2>Example</h2>
<div class="block">
    <img src='http://placekitten.com/g/200/300'>
    <span>foo bar kitten</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I mixed up .closest and .matches in my answer.  Thanks for notifying me :)

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO. You can add the event listener on the div itself and then perform whatever code you like. The reason it doesn't work in your case is because you are adding the event listener to the whole body and thus as the event handler is called, it doesn't recognize the elements you are clicking on even if they are inside the `div`.

Try this instead:

```js
document.querySelector('div#block').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // code...
});
```

Comment: The explanation in this answer misses the actual problem.

Comment: @epascarello You are right, I tried to provide code that works to his specific problem to get it working. Add event handler to the whole body was unnecessary IMO as he wanted it on the `#block` div.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give an id to div and add your event listener to that.

```
<div id="myDiv" class="content">
    // your content goes here
</div>
```

And in javascript

```
const myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
myDiv.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
   // your function goes here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do it. But In my opinion the best way is to make anything `clickable` in JS is use `onClick()` function. You can simply use `onClick=functionName()`

```js
function changeBackground(){   
  let block =  document.getElementsByClassName('block');
  block[0].style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```css
.block{
  height: 50px;
  border : 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="block" onClick="changeBackground()">

<div>
```